# Trouble converting a string to an Int

Tags: swift

The following works in Playground:

```
func stringToInt(numberStr: String!) -> Int {
    print(numberStr)
    return Int(numberStr)!
}

let strNum1: String?
strNum1 = "1"

let result = stringToInt(numberStr: strNum1)
```

It returns 1 as expected.

In Xcode, a similar approach fails:

```
func stringToInt(numberStr: String!) -> Int {

    print("\(numberStr!)")
    let str = "\(numberStr!)"
    print(Int(str))

    return Int(str)!
}
```

The first print produces: Optional(1)
The second print produces: nil
The return statement fails because it is attempting to create an Int from a nil.

It must be something simple but I haven't been able to determine why it's not working.  This is in Swift 3 and Xcode 8 BTW.

@Hamish:

In Xcode, I have a string with a numeric value.  This:

print("number: (selectedAlertNumber) - unit: (selectedAlertUnit)")

...produces this:

number: Optional(1) - unit: Day

Then, I'm checking to see if either selectedAlertNumber of selecterAlertUnit != "-"

```
                    if selectedAlertNumber != "-" && selectedAlertUnit != "-" {
                        // set alert text
                        var unitStr = selectedAlertUnit
                        let alertNumber = stringToInt(numberStr: selectedAlertNumber)
                        if alertNumber > 1 {
                            unitStr.append("s")
                        }
                        let alertText = "...\(selectedAlertNumber) \(unitStr) before event."
                        alertTimeCell.setAlertText(alertText: alertText)


                        // set alert date/time
                    }
```

The let alertNumber = stringToInt... line is how I'm calling the function.  I could just attempt the conversion there but I wanted to isolate the problem by wrapping the conversion in it's own function.

Comment: Forgot to add, converting Int(numberStr) on the Xcode piece (like in the playground) fails also; I was trying a different approach when I posted the example.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this – how are you calling `stringToInt`? A [mcve] would be most helpful. As a side note, you shouldn't annotate `numberStr` as an IUO – it would be much safer as a non-optional parameter.

Comment: @Hamish: updated my original post to show how I'm calling the function.

Comment: Okay, so the problem is further back in your code. `selectedAlertNumber` is *literally* the string `"Optional(1)"`. How are you assigning it?

Comment: Let me work from the top down.  At first I declare and initialize it at the top of the class: var selectedAlertNumber: String = "-"

Comment: In the viewDidLoad, I check for the current editing item that I'm loading from the database (CoreData):

Comment: if itemToEdit?.alarmNumber != 0 {
                selectedAlertNumber = "\(itemToEdit?.alarmNumber)"
            }

Comment: `selectedAlertNumber = "\(itemToEdit?.alarmNumber)"` is the problem. `itemToEdit?.alarmNumber` is an optional, which you need to first unwrap before applying string interpolation (although it begs the question of if `alarmNumber` is a number, why are you turning it into a string and then back into an `Int` later? Why is `selectedAlertNumber` not an `Int` to begin with?).

Comment: Found it, thx to you.  In viewDidLoad changed the assignment line to: selectedAlertNumber = "\\(Int((itemToEdit?.alarmNumber)!))"

Comment: Okay, no problem. Although you should really think twice before force unwrapping something, as you're making a promise that it will *never* be `nil`. In almost all cases, you should write the logic that *handles* the situation where the value is `nil` (e.g by doing optional binding).

Comment: @Hamish, if you add your answer I can mark it as the solution.  Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Using string interpolation to convert values to a String is usually not advised since the output may differ depending on optional status of the value. For example, consider these two functions:

```
func stringToInt(numberStr: String!) -> Int
{
    print("\(numberStr!)")
    let str = "\(numberStr!)"
    return Int(str)!
}

func otherStringToInt(numberStr: String!) -> Int
{
    print(numberStr)
    let str = "\(numberStr)"
    return Int(str)!
}
```

The only difference between these two is the `!` in the second function when using string interpolation to get a `String` type value from `numberStr`. To be more specific, at the same line in function 1 compared to function 2, the string values are very different depending on whether or not the interpolated value is optional:

```
let str1: String = "1"
let str2: String! = "1"
let str3: String? = "1"

let otherStr1 = "\(str1)"  // value: "1"
let otherStr2 = "\(str2)"  // value: "Optional(1)"
let otherStr3 = "\(str2!)" // value: "1"
let otherStr4 = "\(str3)"  // value: "Optional(1)"
let otherStr5 = "\(str3!)" // value: "1"
```

Passing `otherStr2` or `otherStr4` into the `Int` initializer will produce nil, since the string `"Optional(1)"` is not convertible to `Int`. Additionally, this will cause an error during the force unwrap. Instead of using string interpolation in your function, it would be better to just use the value directly since it's already a `String`.

```
func stringToInt(numberStr: String!) -> Int
{
    return Int(numberStr)!
}
```

Let me know if this makes sense.

Also, my own personal feedback: watch out force unwrapping so frequently. In many cases, you're running the risk of getting an error while unwrapping a nil optional.

Comment: Thank you Michael; yes, it makes sense.